# Doing second master's degree on same subject vs applying for PhD without supervisor's letter of recommendation

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, second-degree

I have finished my master's in mathematics from an UK university with a first class distinction. I have always wanted to do a PhD in mathematics. But my supervisor is saying that the recommendation letter that he is going to write may not be the most positive one. I feel devastated, since he didn't mention any reason throughout the supervision. Now, to continue my study in mathematics, I have two options in my hand

(i) To apply for PhD without supervisor's letter of recommendation preferably from usa.

(ii) To do a second master's degree, I prefer from Germany.

I was wondering, what are the chances for me to get a PhD in a decent university, and what are the chances of being accepted for a second master's degree from Germany in a good university. I feel so stuck right now, it will be great if you can help me with this!

Edit: From a second masters degree I am expecting to do a serious research on my topic so that I can get a strong lor from my supervisor for phd

Comment: What would a second masters give you?

Comment: From second masters I am expecting to research extensively on my favorite topic, and get strong letter of recommendation from the supervisor also so I can apply for phd programme

Comment: I think you are simply asking the wrong the question ...

Comment: What should be my question then?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do research other than in a second masters; in a doctoral program, for example. I think the only thing you might gain is a better letter of recommendation. And that isn't guaranteed.

Of course "not the most positive" is open to interpretation, though you know the person better than we do.

My suggestion would be to apply to some doctoral programs along with  applications to second masters programs simultaneously and see what you get. The effort would be approximately the same, except for the number of applications. Use the masters applications as a backup in case none of the doctoral ones work out.

But also apply to a fairly broad spectrum of doctoral programs, not just the top schools in the field. This will increase your chances of success. And your other accomplishments may weigh against a letter that isn't glowing in all details.

I hope the old advisor isn't trying to sabotage your career. That would be cause for complaint. Maybe you can talk them into a better position. Maybe you can get one of their colleagues to speak on your behalf. Maybe you can get much better letters from other faculty.

Don't give up too easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I was wondering, what are the chances for me to get phds into medium universities, that is not the best ones in the field without giving my supervisors letter of recommendation

Comment: Also, will I be at disadvantages position while applying for the second masters degree?

Comment: I don't know how Germany would treat it, but I think that it would be at least somewhat of a disadvantage anywhere. Especially where funding is supplied and the university wants to spread it widely. Generally you want good letters. Who they are from may be less important than that, though questions might be raised without one from your advisor. Maybe especially in Germany, but you'd need advice from someone with specific knowledge of admissions there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am thinking about applying for second master's degree in Germany, and phd at usa. I believe, in my second masters degree letter from my supervisor may not be as important as in the application of phd. Though, I was wondering in general while applying for second kasters degree would I be atba disadvantageous position

Comment: I'd guess that in the US a doctorate would be possible, but the admissions process is broad based. Letters predicting success are relatively important. But they probably don't need to be from your supervisor.

Comment: Yes it's  not written anywhere, but I thought getting a funded doctorate in US without letter of recommendation from the supervisor would be impossible, that's why the question. Do you know anyone who went through similar situation as mine

Comment: Almost all doctoral study in US is funded. Usually with a TA position. These almost always come with tuition forgiveness as well. The big problem will be getting accepted (and perhaps getting a visa). There are very few funded positions with no "work" requirements. More in some fields but not so much in math.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one last question, do you know anyone who got accepted into Phd without any letter of recommendation from supervisor of masters thesis?